# iOS NSURLSession, how to retry in didCompleteWithError

Tags: ios, post, background, nsurlsession

I want to try a post call on my server till it success, I would like to try it each 30 seconds.

So I am using NSURLSession for my call:

```
 NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
task.taskDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading file %@", [path lastPathComponent]];
[task resume];
```

Then if an error occur (no network for example) I have an error in:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
```

My question is how to do the same call in 30 seconds will my app is in background?

I tried with dispatch, NSThread and performSelector but looks like it does not work in background :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A few observations:

1. If you want to try again in a few seconds even if the app is no longer in the foreground, you will presumably just want to ask the OS for a little extra time to perform a finite length task. See [Extending Your App's Background Execution Time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time). If you do that, your standard timer, `dispatch_after`, or whatever, should work fine.

   Note you only have 30 seconds (down from 3 minutes in previous iOS versions) to complete this background task. That having been said, I personally suspect that if a user doesn't have connectivity, there's a good chance that they might not have connectivity within the next 30 seconds, either, so I’m not sure if this retry logic will have any benefit if the app is not running.
2. By the way, rather than retrying in 30 seconds, you might consider [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) so that you are notified when the network becomes available. There's no point in trying again until the network is re-established.
3. Another approach is to use `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier` of `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. See [Downloading Content in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5). If you do this, you have more than 3 minutes for the request to finish. And it will automatically start as soon as connectivity is re-established. The disadvantages of this technique are that (a) the background sessions aren't quite as responsive as foreground sessions; (b) it's limited to iOS 7 and later; and (c) you have to implement delegate-based rendition of `NSURLSession` rather than completion block rendition, which is a little more work.

Frankly, I'd generally be inclined to pursue the third approach, but each has its merits.

Comment: How do you achieve the third approach? Can you provide an example of retrying a download task?

Comment: The beauty of the third approach is that you don't have to do any retry logic. The system will automatically try to perform the request when network connectivity is re-established.

Comment: So if `didCompleteWithError` is called with a non-nil error, does that (possibly) mean that several retry attempts were made before it got to the point of failing with an error?

Comment: And you're getting that with a background `NSURLSession` (i.e. one with a `NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`)?

Comment: I haven't received a non nil error yet. That was a theoretical question. But yes, I'm using `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`.