# Retrying a failed download in URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

How do I resume the download task after a delay?

I had a look at this thread:

[iOS NSURLSession, how to retry in didCompleteWithError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209372/ios-nsurlsession-how-to-retry-in-didcompletewitherror)

The third approach suggested by Rob is what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to set a delay.

So far, I've got something like this:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession*)session task:(NSURLSessionTask*)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError*)error {
  if ( error == nil )
    return;

  NSData* resume_data = error.userInfo[NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData];
  NSURLSessionDownloadTask* new_task = [_session downloadTaskWithResumeData:resume_data];  
  [new_task resume];
}
```

I'd like to wait 10 seconds (say) and then resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[new_task resume]` works, then so will:

```
[new_task performSelector:@selector(resume) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0]
```

Comment: please note that `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` will not work if called from a background thread. try using dispatch_after, it will work from whatever thread (although it also has a few caveats).

Comment: thanks. This did solve the immediate issue of calling a function after a delay.

Answer (score 3):

You should not resume it after a delay.  That will just lead to your app using lots of resources when there's no network connection.

Instead, use [reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to determine when it is appropriate to try again.  Create a reachability object for the exact host from the original URL, and when that reachability object says that the host is reachable, retry the request.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented reachability.